# How to set background realy full of the page in HTML

Tags: html, css

when i want to set the background for my page,  i coded like this code! But it's just quite close to be full , it still has a small " White BackGround " maybe only 5px or 7px on the right , left, top and bottom also :(

```
#background{8
    background-image: url('picture/background.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-size : cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
}
```

Comment: `body{margin:0;padding:0}`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both the background div and whatever may be wrapping it has both margin and padding set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It should be because of default margin/padding added by browser.

So please add `margin:0` and `padding:0` as below

```
 #background{
    background-image: url('picture/background.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    background-size : cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

else just

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin:0;` `padding:0;` as below:

```
#background{8
background-image: url('picture/background.jpg') ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
background-size : cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
top : 0px;
left : 0px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```